# How to have native tkinter.filedialog.ask*filenames like dialog from a python script?

Tags: python, user-interface

How to get a native filedialog (if you are on windows, use windows one, if KDE, use KDE one, and so on) from python ?

I tried `tkinter.filedialog.*`, but it looks 90's and I would like to get a native file dialog. I read the python doc page on ttk : https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/tkinter.ttk.html but there is nothing about filedialogs... (by the way, I'm not tied to tkinter...)

Comment: On windows `tkinter.filedialog` look normal to me.

Comment: Oh, funny, I'm on kde and haven't tested on windows actually. On kde, I get an awful GTK-like dialog themed like the 90's

Comment: Looks like there is a project out there that tries to look more like GTK, https://github.com/j4321/tkFileBrowser

Comment: Actually, I want more like KDE, this is already a gtk-like design...

Comment: On windows and the mac you get a system dialog. On linux you get a dialog provided directly by tkinter.